# Use field value as key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am doing this query

```
db.analytics.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {"event":"USER_SENTIMENT"}
    },
    { $group: {
            _id: {brand:"$data.brandId",sentiment:"$data.sentiment"},
            count: {$sum : 1}
        }
    },
    { $group: {
            _id: "$_id.brand",
            sentiments: {$addToSet : {sentiment:"$_id.sentiment", count:"$count"}}
        }
    }
])
```

Which generates that :

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 57,
            "sentiments" : [ 
                {
                    "sentiment" : "Meh",
                    "count" : 4
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 376,
            "sentiments" : [ 
                {
                    "sentiment" : "Meh",
                    "count" : 1
                }, 
                {
                    "sentiment" : "Happy",
                    "count" : 1
                }, 
                {
                    "sentiment" : "Confused",
                    "count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

But What I want is that :

```
[ 
    {
        "_id" : 57,
        "Meh" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 376,
        "Meh" : 1,
        "Happy" : 1,
        "Confused" : 1
    }
]
```

Any idea on how to transform that? The blocking point for me is to transform a value into a key.

Comment: There really isn't a way to do that in the aggregation framework without specifically and consistently having the same keys for all documents. If you "really" need this then use mapReduce instead. But the aggregate way should be faster and you could always transform the results outside of the aggregation pipeline. Or is that last point what you are actually asking?

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you very much. You answered my question. I am new to the mongodb world so if you have any comment on my query, don't hesitate!